# Possibility of a civilization on (or around) Planet Nine

Tags: science-based, biology, aliens, solar-system

Could there be life on or around [Planet Nine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Nine) (a real-world planet in our Solar System, which has recently been discovered through indirect methods)? Of course, it probably receives nearly no solar energy, but there are other energy sources. For example, [Jupiter's moon Europa may get energy from tidal and volcanic sources that may support life](http://www.space.com/26905-jupiter-moon-europa-alien-life.html).

How plausible is it that there is:

- life
- intelligence
- civilization
- society similar to our own

on Planet Nine or one of its moons (or otherwise around it)?

[image]

Note: I was thinking along the lines of them having originated there, not having migrated there.

Note: I would like answers to be at least somewhat scientifically sound (I was debating whether or not to tag this [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science).)

Comment: How is it plausible, or how plausible is it? Which one do you mean to ask?

Comment: I'm sure there's a colony of space yetis who enjoy the frigid climate.

Comment: And I'm sure the yetis hunt interstellar travelers and the dinosaur looking things they ride.

Comment: @Avernium I never said it was *probable*. Indeed, I never said it was *plausible* either; that's why I asked.

Comment: @PyRulez I'm just poking fun, I think it's a great question.

Comment: @Avernium Also, if there are space yetis on it, I say we name the planet Avernium.

Comment: Are we assuming the gas giant core hypothesis that Batygin and Brown have implied, or are we just imagining any type of planet?

Comment: @HDE226868 The one in the link (which I think is the one you are talking about), not just any ninth planet (of which there are a bunch apparently, including sketchy ones). (As far as I know, there is no evidence for or against moons at this point.)

Answer (score 3):

An advanced technological civilization can survive and even thrive everywhere there's any matter to use. Fusion, anti-matter, etc. You can have whatever aliens you want there.

Biological water- and carbon-based life however would have about as much chance of existing/surviving there on their own as a molten-iron-based life-form would have on the surface of the Earth.

But let's be nice. Perhaps Planet Nine was once a nice, inner-system Neptunian World with an Earth-sized companion satellite. The planet itself is too big for Earth-like life. The oversized companion moon would have had lots of water, carbon, all the good stuff.

Later on, just a few million years ago, through an unfortunate interaction with a nearby star and Jupiter, Planet IX (locals call it Cthulhu) got expelled into the cold outer reaches. Talk about bad luck. The highly advanced civilization on IX decided not to invade Earth, which was lacking the requisite technological infrastructure. A small genetic modification was induced into one of the ape species on Planet III (the Waterplanet), as part of the IX-iforming process. The apes would build the industrial infrastructure, and the IXians would later come and use it once in place.

While they wait, 99% of the population was put on Cryo/Virtuality, and a small crew on a billion of the Elder race maintains the industrial plant and occasionally keeps an eye on those Earth-apes.

When the time is ripe, C̱͔̲̙̳͐̓̔̉ͭ̀t̨̾͋̀ͫͧ͒̚҉̮̟ͅḣ̛͍͎̰̬͇͉̫̆ͮ͛̌͌ͯu̴̬͚̼͇̰ͮ̍̋l̤ͮͦ̋̚h̰͚̜ͭͣͬ̊̒ͨͨ͆͡ů̯̜͓̪̉ͪ̄͋̔̈́ ̨͈̰͍̙̤̟͍͑ͤ̌͛̄w̪̳̣̣̌͊̂ͩͦį͎̣̤̥͕͎͙̦̍̀͊ͥ͂ͩl̥͓̖̪̥͖̦̼̦̓̾͑ͤ͗̅̏̃́l̏̓̈ͧ͏̱̹̫̙͕͔͜ ̯͖̗̦̠̯ͤ̑̏̃̈́ͨ̏̎͝rͧ̔҉͉̻̜͇̙̪i̶̬͖̠͔̼̖͒͗̉̂͊͝s̍̀̈́̐̿͋͏͎̜̻̦̼͙͖ę͈̂ͩ̔ͥ̓̓̾̕ ̈́̈́̆҉̶̡͕͓̞͇̬͙ậ͙͇̠͔͈̗̲ͯģ̯͍͕̳̿̊̋̓̈́͠à̷̡̱̹̞͐ͬ̾̈́̌ͧ͛i̵̷̴̙̳̲̦ͦͤ̂̈n̜̯͇̹̲͐̈́̋̈́̑͠

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of them having developed there based on some non solar energy source, not being migrants.

Comment: Their world moved, but They haven't migrated. Yet. Deep they sleep, waiting for the Day to come.

Comment: How do you do that Cthulhu type?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure the above is scientifically sound (Planet Nine was probably far away from the start, and surely wasn't near the earth after life began.)

Comment: @PyRulez I am betting on copy/paste C̱͔̲̙̳͐̓̔̉ͭ̀t̨̾͋̀ͫͧ͒̚҉̮̟ͅḣ̛͍͎̰̬͇͉̫̆ͮ͛̌͌ͯu̴̬͚̼͇̰ͮ̍̋l̤ͮͦ̋̚h̰͚̜ͭͣͬ̊̒ͨͨ͆͡ů̯̜͓̪̉ͪ̄͋̔̈́ ̨͈̰͍̙̤̟͍͑ͤ̌͛̄w̪̳̣̣̌͊̂ͩͦį͎̣̤̥͕͎͙̦̍̀͊ͥ͂ͩl̥͓̖̪̥͖̦̼̦̓̾͑ͤ͗̅̏̃́l̏̓̈ͧ͏̱̹̫̙͕͔͜ ̯͖̗̦̠̯ͤ̑̏̃̈́ͨ̏̎͝rͧ̔҉͉̻̜͇̙̪i̶̬͖̠͔̼̖͒͗̉̂͊͝s̍̀̈́̐̿͋͏͎̜̻̦̼͙͖ę͈̂ͩ̔ͥ̓̓̾̕ ̈́̈́̆҉̶̡͕͓̞͇̬͙ậ͙͇̠͔͈̗̲ͯģ̯͍͕̳̿̊̋̓̈́͠à̷̡̱̹̞͐ͬ̾̈́̌ͧ͛i̵̷̴̙̳̲̦ͦͤ̂̈n̜̯͇̹̲͐̈́̋̈́̑͠

Comment: @VilleNiemi Ỳ̦͔͎̜ͮ̒ͬͨͩ̈͢ͅo͖̯̹͎̓͋́̅̈ͨ̎͒̀u̴̢̦̳͇̟͖̔͑̀̏ͅ ͆̚͏̶͕̥͕͇̠̮̩d̛̗̮̤̬͉̙͌̍ͨ͗ͨ̋́̔ǎ̡͉͈͕̱̞̣̌ͯͨ̂͘ͅͅr̢͔̙̜ͯ̈ͬ̅̃̕ęͯ̎̉͛҉̱̟ ̵̡̙̙͖̰̫͍̒̎͊̆̐͞q̫͉̬̱̦ͭ̈́̀͆̂͟ū̷͙̝̻̱̮͛̑ͩ́́̑ͅͅe̢̛̞͓̳͈͍͚͖̳ͥ̏ͮ̌̓s̖̮̝͉̳̀ͧ̆̐t͈̝ͨ͆́̒̐̅ͦ́͜i̶̥̲̱͕̹̜ͣͫ̄̓ͦ̑͋͂́͝ͅo̡̲͓͉̜̖̜̫̣̍̊͞ͅn̷̰̜͔̯̅̈́͝ ̴̖͈͌ͭ̌͗̃͑ͬ͐͠m̵̪͚͖̖ͭ̔̌ͭ̈̑͆̚͜͝ē̼̠͓͇͍͙̭̥̼͆ͪ͘͢!̖̠̬̬͕͓̊̔͛́́?̛͔̥̺͚͔̜̯̲̄̈́̓̐?̪̗̗̳͍̿́͌̽̀

Comment: @PyRulez To be fair, some models predict that it originally formed at a distance comparable to those of Uranus and Neptune - much further in.

Comment: @HDE226868, to be fair, most models predict it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa Very true - although those models aren't necessarily applicable. The objections raised about the applicability of the Nice model might be null if we accept a different formation date, for example.

Comment: @PyRulez http://eeemo.net/

Answer (score 3):

The major problem here is that, while we don't know for sure what this planet is like - after all, the paper ([Batygin & Brown (2015)](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/0004-6256/151/2/22;jsessionid=9DAB98EED9CB30448604A2F4CA0F8752.c5.iopscience.cld.iop.org)) was based on simulations of the movements of Kuiper Belt Objects that matched observations - Batygin and Brown have implied that it may be the core of a 5th gas giant. I wrote [an answer on Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13310/how-was-the-hypothetical-ninth-planet-kicked-so-far-out-of-the-solar-system/13311#13311) detailing the basic mechanics of the planet, but that's mainly irrelevant.

So if we allow for the first possibility, we have a core of about 10 Earth masses floating along at a couple hundred AU from the Sun on an orbit with relatively high eccentricity (it's believed that e~0.6). This is, quite frankly, a terrible situation for life, for a few reasons:

- The core is most likely not composed or compounds making it suitable for life.
- There is most likely not geothermal activity.
- The Sun is extremely faint, so photosynthesis isn't easy.

What if the planet retained some of its gaseous envelope, as Brown has suggested? As a side note, this also arises from those theories that this planet is actually a rogue planet, although I'm not sure which one is more prevailing at the moment (I would think it's the former). We now have a [mini-Neptune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-Neptune). This would mean that we have an envelope of hydrogen, helium, and water, ammonia, and other compounds in lower concentrations.

The possibility of life here is low - certainly not life as we know it. The best chance may be for life on a moon of the planet, which could squeeze out - pun intended - some energy from tidal heating, thanks to its parent planet.

But the odds of this are low - not zero, but low.

Comment: I did list Europa as an example in the OP.

Comment: @PyRulez Yeah, I think a Europa-like situation is your best bet here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will have is the absolutely ridiculous cold and lack of any energy source. Life needs a source of energy in order to be able to do anything. Even on earth our best [cold adapted life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychrophile) is limited to -15 or -20 degrees celsius.

We're not aware of any life based on other substances that are liquid at much lower temperatures, but that does not mean it could not exist. We just don't know.

Assuming carbon/water is the only option for life though then the only realistic way to get temperatuers high enough at this distance from the sun is geothermal in a planet or tidal heating in a moon. How viable that is would depend very much on the nature and composition of the planet.