# Wizards from (a moon of) Planet Nine are causing Blizzards. How should we convince them to stop?

Tags: magic, aliens, solar-system

Scientists recently discovered [Planet Nine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34009/possibility-of-a-civilization-on-or-around-planet-nine). Planet Nine inhabitants (or rather the the inhabitants of one of its moons) has been observing the Earth through probes for some time (it is easy to send things closer to the sun than farther away). Once they found out that we discovered the planet, they told their wizards to send [Blizzards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_2016_United_States_winter_storm) to cause blizzards on certain parts of the Earth.

What can we do to convince them to stop the Blizzard?

- They are tracking our communications with secret probes.
- They can send stuff to us, but not us to them easily (besides information), because of the sun's gravity.
- We don't know their motivation.

Comment: What is their motivation for sending blizzards? Are they trying to kill us? Why?

Comment: It's not part of the question actually, you should specifically state that we don't know their motivations :)

Comment: Since they've been observing our planet for some time, they knew we were close to finding their planet, but waited until we actually discovered it to send the blizzards. It's possible the equate blizzards with blinding snow and low visibility, and somehow think the blizzards will stop us from detecting the great secret they have nearby...

Comment: Great, they counteract global warming *and* drought!

Comment: Wow, take a look at the related. That thing is *dead on*!

Comment: **it is easy to send things closer to the sun than farther away)** sort of true for a *flyby* but not for stopping when you get there.  Look at the Messenger mission for example. It's energetically as difficult to get to Mercury as it is to get to Saturn!

Comment: @JDługosz Well yeah, but what if you are just dropping cargo/leaving a probe behind, while the rest of the ship keeps going?

Comment: Then your delta-v can be just your orbital velocity at your starting point. Cancel that and you fall toward the sun even though you'll be going at comet speeds when you get there.  Don't lose enough and you'll never get close enough to the sun to visit the inner planet!  Comet speed: drop-off means kaboom, you know.

Comment: @JDługosz I mean you send a cargo ship, the cargo ship shoots off a lighter load, and then goes somewhere else (such as back to Planet Nine, or the sun).

Comment: This would be a better question if you removed the word "attack", which hints at their motives. If we really don't know their motives and you remove the word "attack", it's quite possible this is their way of greeting us.

Comment: @barrycarter good catch. Fixed.

Comment: @sumelic [Are you sure lizards would be safer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/earth-visited-by-an-enormous-creature)? (RIP Brian Aldiss...)

Answer (score 2):

If there is a Planet Nine out there, then it will be really dark and cold, being really, really, really far away from the sun.  I assume that they are some kind of alien on Planet Nine that can withstand this type of cold, but maybe they don't understand that our planet isn't just the same temperature.  Maybe for them, a blizzard is a good thing; warmer than normal, or maybe for some kind of religious reason, or nourishment.  If we could explain to them that for us, a blizzard is bad, maybe they would stop it.

On the other hand, they did send probes to our planet, so they probably understand that we don't like blizzards and are doing this with some sinister motive.  We are at a disadvantage here because of our lack of magic and difficulty of sending things to them.  We could capture one of their probes and use it as ransom, but that would probably only heighten their anger.  We could somehow send them a message asking them to stop, but I assume that we've tried that already.  The only other option is to be nice to them: promise that we have limited technological capabilities, that we are peaceful and stupid, and that we won't try to take over their planet.  War would not work, since they have a transportation advantage, spies, and really powerful wizard dudes.

But it's okay if that doesn't work, because then we'd get infinite snow days.

Answer (score 1):

The blizzards are incidental. The point is that we are being attacked by a hostile alien force here.

We can share information with them, therefore. The first thing to do is to set up some diplomatic relations and talk to them. We need to ask them why they are attacking us, and what can we do to make them stop attacking us. Assuming they respond and their demands are reasonable and we are able to comply, then we comply and they stop attacking us. End of problem.

Assuming they don't respond to our diplomacy, then we're pretty much screwed. With our current technology, there's not really anything we can do to affect a superior (they can manipulate weather on planets hundreds of millions miles away) hostile (and possible magical) alien force at the far edge of our solar system. We put up with the blizzards until the earth is snowed under and we all die.

Assuming they respond but we can't meet their demands. Same outcome as above, lots of snow and death.

The nuclear option will no doubt be brought up by our fearless leaders here on earth. Assuming we can actually outfit a rocket and modify enough to carry a nuclear and navigate its way to planet nine. Since the aliens are monitoring everything we do, and they are clearly technologically superior, anything launched towards planet nine would be intercepted and destroyed long before it posed any threat to them. This include probes and maned missions.

So basically unless they talk to us and tell us what they want, with our current tech there's not really anything we can do to stop the blizzards from planet nine.